# Managing local/form state on angular container vs redux

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, state-management

I've now experimented with several approaches to manage form states of components.

For this example I'll use a custom component that can select a user from a dropdown, and add them with a button, and then show each user in a table row. Each row will have a startDate & endDate and a checkbox to clear the dates.
And afterward, send the form for submission.

Roughly something like this `container`:

```
<user-selector [users]="users$ | async"></user-selector>
<user-row *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
  <input>{{user.startDate}}</input>
  <checkbox [value]="user.default"></checkbox>
  <input>{{user.endDate}}</divinput
</user-row>
```

**Approach 1:**

Dispatch states to store for the following separate components:

`<user-selector>`:

- `SelectUser(user.id)`
- `AddUser(user.id)`

Each ngFor `user-row`:

- `SetUserDate(user.id, dateType, date)`
- `SetUserDefault(user.id)`

`container`:

- `SaveUser(users)`

Now my state is always in sync and I can trace back any previous state, and can use the redux "time-travel" to see if everything keeps working when I do that.

Maybe the messiest is the `SetUserDate`, because it needs so many inputs to make it work (dateType is so that I don't need two seperate actions)
The others are pretty straightforward, and the reducers make sure the data is updated. 
Then finally, one action `SaveUser` that accepts the current `users$` state and dispatches an async action.

**Approach 2:**

Create a formGroup for each row:

```
const form = new FormGroup( users: new FormArray(generateGroups(users)));

generateGroups (users: User[]) => {
  users.forEach((user: User) => {
     return {
        startDate: new FormControl(user.startDate),
        defaultDate: new FormControl(false),
        endDate: new FormControl(user.endDate)
     };
  });
}
```

This now just needs to be shaped into similar html as the example through some `ngFor`'s.

Here I run into some issues:

- Setting the checkbox should directly modify `startDate` & `endDate` to `''`.

I could have do `form.valueChanges.subscribe` to listen to the changes either on both start & end seperately or combineLatest could possibly work. And then either modify the `generateGroups` function to accomodate for this change, or update the `users` object directly and run `generateGroups` again, or do `patchValue`.

One problem I'd have modifying the state on the component, is that you're doing basically going to modify/update the state, and avoid modifying the original state (unless the `users` object is already a clone, through either using a `new User()` model or just cloning it with `{ ...user }` or similar.

- Adding a User

I could do something like:

```
addUser(user: User) {
  this.users.push(user);
}
```

And something similar for removing a user.
But in the above example I'm modifying the original user object, which is problematic if that user is bound/references to the store, thus modifying the store directly.
Which would call for a different solution:

```
addUser(user: User) {
  let newUsers = { ...this.users };
  newUsers.push(user);
  return newUsers;
}
```

Then the `return` value should be handled as well, and the only sensible thing would be to then not do the latter, but stick to the former, and make sure the `this.users` is already cloned, avoiding mutating the state. Through methods stated above, where `new Users(users)` would make the most sense.

**Main issue**

What we end up doing in `Approach 2` is doing exactly what a reducer does, but locally, and without having any event/state history.

I'd like to keep the needed actions to a minimum, and I'm sort of fine with `Approach 1`, but that can cause a lot of actions to be created if the form is bigger (and it is). Which leads me to a 3rd possible approach:

**Approach 3**

Use `formGroups` like the 2nd approach, and then listen to individual changes with `valueChanges`, so:

```
form.controls[0].defaultDate.controls.valueChanges.subscribe((changes) => {
   // Either dispatch action 
   this.store.dispatch(new SetUserDefault(this.user.id));
   // Or `patchValue`.
   form.controls[0].startDate.patchValue('');
   form.controls[0].endDate.patchValue('');
});
```

Or I could subscribe to the whole form and figure out what has changed, and which action to take (e.g. either dispatch, or patchValue) when and then also how. (Which sounds like a job for a reducer)

**Lastly**

What is the best thing to do here, considering this form has at least 4 more different kinds of form-like components, that modify state before sending it.

- Not using any redux actions at all, except when doing `SaveUser`, would mean that I have no timeline in between the inital state of the form until the very end.
- Using only redux means I have to make a lot of verbose actions, and make reducers for each action.
- Using both like the last approach means letting `formControls` manage as much as the state as possible, but have to subscribe to each individual user-item, or alternatively, I could listen to the whole form, but then have to work with matching `FormGroup` indexes and would make it more complicated than necessary.